# Strange usage of the third person s in ancient language

Tags: grammar

I recently listened to the original soundtrack of the Mary Poppins film and realized that Bert sometimes utilizes strange grammar:

"Good luck will rub off when I shakes hands with you"

Or

"I does what I likes and I likes what I do"

Is that what people used to say back then or is it just an artistic figure of speech?

Comment: What's the “ancient” part?

Comment: Maybe ancient was not the right word for it, but still, it's not exactly today's language

Comment: It was an _attempt_ by the writers of the musical to sound like lower class  people in [Edwardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwardian_era) London. It's not necessarily an accurate depiction of how they used to speak at the beginning of the last century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That (set in the early 20th Century) is not "ancient".  That is a (supposed) dialect of uneducated Londoners.  Note that Bert (uneducated chimney sweep) says things like this, not Mary Poppins herself (who has a very posh accent).